# Multiple Uploads in cloudinary using Node Js and ForEach loop

Tags: arrays, node.js, foreach, cloudinary

I have an input tag to upload multiple images and upload them to cloudinary using cloudinary and formidable packages.

Ideally, i wanted to pull the URL and save it in my DB where i have all the rest information.

But failed to retrieve the URLs shown below in array.

Target it to create an object to be saved in the DB with the URLs.

```js
app.post("/newcampbook",(req,res)=>{
  new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true }).parse(req,(err,fields,file)=>{
   if(!err){     
     var pathArray = [];
        file.image.forEach(e =>{
            pathArray.push(e.path)
        })
        var savedUrl = [];
        pathArray.forEach(e =>{
            cloudinary.uploader.upload(e, (err,savedImage)=>{
                if(!err){
                    savedUrl.push(savedImage.url)
                    console.log(savedUrl)
                }
            })
        })
    res.send("Testing to upload")
   } else {
    console.log(err);
    res.send("Error")
   }
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to synchronize the uploads using an async callback library like `async` or convert to promises. I prefer promises but the cloudinary library needs a promise wrapper. 
 Luckily node 8+ comes with a built-in promisify function that converts callbacks into promises. With promises your code would look like:

```
 const { promisify } = require('util')

 // Converts cloudinary callback interface into promise
 const uploadAsync = promisify(cloudinary.uploader.upload.bind(cloudinary.uploader))

 app.post("/newcampbook",(req,res)=>{
 new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true }).parse(req, async (err,fields,file)=>{
   if(!err){     
     var pathArray = [];
     file.image.forEach(e =>{
       pathArray.push(e.path)
     })
     var savedUrl = [];
     for(let e of pathArray) {
       const { url } = await uploadAsync(e)
       savedUrl.push(url)
     }
     res.send("Testing to upload")
   }else{
    console.log(err);
    res.send("Error")
  }
 })
})
```

Now ^ that code will execute each upload synchronously one after the other. If you want to run all uploads at once (which is what your original code is doing) then it would look like:

```
 const { promisify } = require('util')

 // Converts cloudinary callback interface into promise
 const uploadAsync = promisify(cloudinary.uploader.upload.bind(cloudinary.uploader))

 app.post("/newcampbook",(req,res)=>{
 new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true }).parse(req, async (err,fields,file)=>{
   if(!err){     
     var pathArray = [];
     file.image.forEach(e =>{
       pathArray.push(e.path)
     })
     var savedUrl = (await Promise.all(pathArray.map(uploadAsync))).map(({ url }) => url)
     res.send("Testing to upload")
   }else{
    console.log(err);
    res.send("Error")
  }
 })
})
```

If you want to use `async` library, then look at the `parallel` and `series` functions which can do the same things directly to callbacks.

Comment: I was stuck for two days with the loop changing every single syntax trying to get it done. You are awesome. I might need to read / watch some videos about promise, async and await to know more. Thank you and much appreciated

Comment: No problem. If it works for you please consider accepting the answer! Good Luck!