# Asynchronicity issue: why does the second part of my function run before a loop event finishes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a route on an Express server that updates a User profile. The User profile is updated before I have finished to parse the data to update. How so?

I want to update two const: newProfilePicture & newOtherPictures. They are correctly updated, but after the user has been updated, so it's useless. How to fix this asynchronicity issue?

Here is the function:

```js
router.post("/upload-images", upload.array("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  try {
    if (req.files) {
      let newProfilePicture = null;
      let newOtherPictures = [];
      req.files.forEach(({ path, originalname }) => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(
          path,
          {
            resource_type: "image",
            public_id: `myapp/users/${userId}/${originalname}`,
            crop: "scale",
            quality: "auto",
          },
          (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              return fs.unlinkSync("./" + path);
            }
            fs.unlinkSync("./" + path);
            if (originalname === "main") {
              return (newProfilePicture = res.secure_url);
            }
            return newOtherPictures.push({
              id: originalname,
              url: res.secure_url,
            });
          }
        );
      });
// THIS PART IS COMPLETE BEFORE THE req.files.forEach IS DONE
      const user = await User.findById(userId);
      const { otherPictures, profilePicture } = updatePictures(
        newProfilePicture,
        newOtherPictures,
        user
      );
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        { profilePicture, otherPictures },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.send("upload images success");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err", err);
    return res.status(500).send("upload images failed");
  }
});
```

Comment: Because `cloudinary.uploader.upload(()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  Your `.forEach()` loop runs to completion starting all the `cloudinary.uploader.upload(()` calls running and then the second part of your function runs and then, sometime later all the `cloudinary.uploader.upload(()` calls finish.  Does `cloudinary.uploader.upload(()` have a promise interface that can be used instead of a plain callback interface?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: What is the point of the two `return` statements inside the `.forEach()` loop.  What are those supposed to do?  Since `.forEach()` does not pay any attention to a value returned from its callback, they are not currently doing anything useful.  But, I'm wondering what they are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Similar question/answer here: [Multple uploads in cloudinary using nodejs and forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979043/multiple-uploads-in-cloudinary-using-node-js-and-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `cloudinary.uploader.upload()` runs asynchronously. Since you mentioned it doesn't have promise interface, you can convert the callback to promise using NodeJS's `util.promise` function as it's error first callback.

```
const { promisify } = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");
const cloudinaryUpload = promisify(cloudinary.uploader.upload.bind(cloudinary.uploader))

router.post("/upload-images", upload.array("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files) {
      return res.send("no images in the request body");
    }
    let newProfilePicture = null;
    let newOtherPictures = [];
    for (const { path, originalName } of req.files) {
      try {
        const response = await cloudinaryUpload(path, {
          resource_type: "image",
          public_id: `myapp/users/${userId}/${originalName}`,
          crop: "scale",
          quality: "auto",
        });
        await fs.promises.unlink("./" + path);
        if (originalname === "main") {
          newProfilePicture = response.secure_url;
          continue;
        }
        newOtherPictures.push({
          id: originalName,
          url: response.secure_url,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        //do what you want if there is an error
        //throw error if you want
        await fs.promises.unlink("./" + path);
      }
    }
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const { otherPictures, profilePicture } = updatePictures(
      newProfilePicture,
      newOtherPictures,
      user
    );
    //use User.updateOne() as you don't need the doc back
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      userId,
      { profilePicture, otherPictures },
      { new: true }
    );
    return res.send("upload images success");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("err", err);
    return res.status(500).send("upload images failed");
  }
});
```

Comment: You left out the second part of the function where the profile is updated which is the part that is executing at the wrong time in the original question.

Comment: > which is the part that is executing at the wrong time in the original question
Yes. Above code will wait for the first part to finish executing before it starts with the second one.

Comment: So, why don't you complete the answer and include that code in the route handler?  Your answer as it stands now is illustrative, but incomplete when you could very well make it complete by including the rest of the code in the route handler.

Comment: Also, `await fs.unlink("./" + path);` is wrong.  You could do `await fs.promises.unlink("./" + path);`

Comment: @jfriend00 added rest of the code. Please check the import statement for fs.promises

Comment: It is not recommended to use the symbol `fs` as an alias for `fs.promises` because that both confuses people reading your code and removes the ability to use other `fs` methods such as `fs.createReadStream()`.  Please use a different symbol for `fs.promises`.  I use `fsp` in my code.

Comment: I agree. Changed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, there is still a slight issue: if I don't add a return in the final "if(originalname==="main") statement, the image may be both pushed in the newProfilePicture and the newOtherPictures const. But adding the return stops the function, and I can't update the user. The only solution is to write two if (if === main and if !== main) but it's ugly. Would you have a suggestion? Also, why do you use fs.promisify?

Comment: Sync functions blocks [Event Loop](https://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html) and callbacks leads to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: @DoneDeal0 You can add `continue` to not go further(I have added in answer )